# php how can I create russian folder

Tags: php, utf-8, directory, encode

I am using the following code on WAMP server Windows 7 to create a folder with Russian name but the actual folder has name like ÐÐ°Ð¸Ð¼ÐµÐ½Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ

```
<?php
  $name="Наименования";
     if (!mkdir($name, 0, true)) 
          echo "no";
     else 
          echo "yes";
?>
```

How can I do that properly? My images in that folder can not be seen by the browser.

Comment: There are tens, if not hundreds, of questions like this on SO. Use the search function before asking questions. If you find a question/answer(s) that helps you then vote them up.